# Struts action inheritance

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts 2. I have a question regarding the inheritance of struts action classes.

For an application i am using struts2-jquery plugin to make use of the jquery grid tag. I have a simple struts action class called

> TestAction which extends abstract class TestParent.
>
> TestParent extends ActionSupport and it has the protected variables like gridmodel, sord,records etc and their getters and setters. It also has the execute method and gridmodel data is loaded through abstract methods to be implemented by subclass.

When TestAction extends TestParent it implements the abstract method getGridData and get data from DB. TestAction is mapped in struts.xml. Problem arises when i run it on server. The grid is empty but the console shows all the grid data i print in execute method of TestParent and getGridData of TestAction. The gridmodel is of type List of Map object.

When I remove the inheritence and include all grid parameters and execute method in TestAction the grid shows the data. Is java inheritance in struts a problem?

I have many reports that i need to show in a jquery grid. Therefore i opted this approach. What better approach should i adopt.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show both actions?? Please update your post with the action code

Comment: Ya i have added both actions. Please help

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to Struts2, I expect this to be a misconfiguration, as I've had his problem many times, and every single time I usually forgot to create the getters for the necessary data, or didn't make them public. I also always use an abstract class named ActionHelper where I extend ActionSupport and implement all the necessary interfaces for interceptors.

1.)

Please make sure your getters look like this and are not overridden in the class that extends the abstract class:

```
public List<Map> getGridData() {
            ...
    return gridData;
}
```

I never tried defining the execute() method in the abstract class, if this is a problem you can maybe just override it in the subclass and return super.execute().

Please also make sure you return the correct result.

2.)

My colleague worked with the grid, and I know that he had problems getting to the data because it made an AJAX call for another action to return the necessary data that gets shown. Please make sure that the sj:grid is configured to use the correct action, returning the correct data.

3.)

Use the debugger. At the moment you use the console, but just set a breakpoint in your action in the subclass and Debug the code. When you are there, you can see all the variables.

4.)

If this doesn't fix the problem (which I really don't expect), please paste here all the code involved, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code. I ve changed the TestParent from being abstract class to a normal class. Now execute method is written in TestAction. Though i run this the grid is not getting populated and yet i see the console with print statements written in getGridData method.

TestParent.java

```
 public class TestParent extends ActionSupport{

protected List<Map<String, Object>> gridModel;

protected Integer rows = 0;

protected Integer page = 0;

protected String sord;

protected String sidx;

protected String searchField;

protected String searchString;

protected String searchOper;

protected Integer total = 0;

protected Integer records = 0;

public List<Map<String, Object>> getGridModel() {
    return gridModel;
}

public void setGridModel(List<Map<String, Object>> gridModel) {
    this.gridModel = gridModel;
}

public Integer getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(Integer rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

public Integer getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public String getSord() {
    return sord;
}

public void setSord(String sord) {
    this.sord = sord;
}

public String getSidx() {
    return sidx;
}

public void setSidx(String sidx) {
    this.sidx = sidx;
}

public String getSearchField() {
    return searchField;
}

public void setSearchField(String searchField) {
    this.searchField = searchField;
}

public String getSearchString() {
    return searchString;
}

public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
    this.searchString = searchString;
}

public String getSearchOper() {
    return searchOper;
}

public void setSearchOper(String searchOper) {
    this.searchOper = searchOper;
}

public Integer getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public Integer getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(Integer records) {
    this.records = records;
}

 }
```

TestAction.java

```
public class TestAction extends TestParent{
@Override
public String execute(){

        int to = (rows * page);
    int from = to - rows;
    gridModel = getGridData();

    records = getTotalNumberOfRecords();

    //calculate the total pages for the query
    total =(int) Math.ceil((double)records / (double)rows);

    return SUCCESS;
}


protected List<Map<String, Object>> getGridData() {
    String sql = "Select * from Sales.Customer";
    List<Map<String, Object>> map =null;
    try {
        map = DBConnect.getResult(sql, DBType.MAIN_DB);
        System.out.println("gridModel data :");
        for(Map<String,Object> m :map){
            System.out.print("Customer_ID : "+m.get("Customer_ID")+" ");
            System.out.println("FirstName : "+m.get("FirstName"));
        }
    } catch (DBException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return map;
}

protected Integer getTotalNumberOfRecords() {

    String sql = "select count(*) as count from Sales.Customer";
    int count = 0;
    try {
        List<Map<String, Object>> map = DBConnect.getResult(sql,
                DBType.MAIN_DB);
        count = (Integer) map.get(0).get("count");
        System.out.println("no of records : " + count);
    } catch (DBException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return count;
}
 }
```

In struts.xml :

```
 <action name="testList" class="com.mis.struts.action.TestAction">
        <result name="success" type="json" />
    </action>
```

test.jsp :

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>

  <sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Customers"
    dataType="json"
    href="testList"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true"
    multiselect="true"     
    viewrecords="true"          
>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="Customer_ID" index="Customer_ID" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="false" hidden="true" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="FirstName" index="FirstName" title="First Name" sortable="true" search="true"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="LastName" index="LastName" title="Last Name" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="Address" index="Address" title="Address" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="Email" index="Email" title="Email"  sortable="false"/>
</sjg:grid>
```

Comment: What you have done is made a `TestParent` a POJO.I don't see any use of `TestParent`.is it not good to decrlare any POJO what you action is doing and can init you POJO in you action class.

Comment: Well i had the execute method in it and some abstract methods as it was an abstract class it did not work even then.